# Invoicing in Magento 2, getting "We can't save the invoice right now" and "Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly"

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments, magento2, invoice

Those errors in the title are half lying, though. It is saving **something** in the invoice table. I just can't tell if the records look like what is supposed to be saved. The order then shows as being paid and closed, and the proper emails go out. The orders aren't showing up in the sellers' transactions, though, which I suspect has to do with the failed save? That's a problem, in addition to not being able to tell my sellers "just ignore those bright red errors when you're invoicing".

I know it doesn't help that I have several modules installed (Webkul's Multivendor Marketplace and Advanced Booking, plus the Stripe module).

I have zero errors in any logfiles, including mysql logs, frustratingly. I'm new to both PHP and Magento, but I've combed through the code and have narrowed down to where the error is logged, if not why it's being thrown. I'm hesitant to c/p since the code technically belongs to Webkul, but since they will only "help" if I give them root access to my clients' servers, I'll provide a snippet if needed.

Stripe is set to only take credit card payments, with authorize only initially, and then capture when the sellers invoice. The test charges are all working beautifully, and I can see all the successes in both the remote Stripe logs and the ones local to my server. The error is ultimately being thrown in app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Controller/Order/Invoice.php (which does wend its way through module-sales on its way to the db). I think the issue goes as deep as the db save call in vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php, though, since a rollback error is also being triggered. My thought was that I must somehow be feeding it bad data, for the error to run that deep. I **have** hacked up the front-end, a bit, which has affected some input, but I'm pretty sure nothing that touches the invoicing.

I hope all this helps someone to help me! I'm happy to share whatever (within reason) screenshots/codesnippets/db queries/log output (as useless as that's currently being). Thank you!!

[ETA] I forgot to mention that all the standard fixes around duplicate order/invoice ids are not the case. I wish it were that easy.

Comment: are you using the Webkul Stripe add-on for their marketplace module, or a Stripe module by a different developer?

Comment: I'm using the official Stripe module, from the Magento Marketplace. https://marketplace.magento.com/stripe-stripe-payments.html

Comment: I don't think that the two modules are compatible out of the box, that's why Webkul has its own Stripe module. Either way, if you can find where the exception is thrown, log it with $e->getMessage() and $e->getTraceAsString() and post it here.

Comment: I finally got back to this, and a nudge from @snez sent me over to Webkul to check their modules. Which mentioned a php package I did not have installed, and ended up being the key. I had stripe/stripe-payments, but also needed stripe/stripe-php. Now, like magic, everything flows beautifully!

Thanks for helping, snez, and for giving me a way to capture errors!

Comment: Small correction. Apparently it already had v7.68.0 of stripe-php. An upgrade to v7.69.0 in this project was the trick.

Comment: You actually got them working together? If so could you send me a message at snez@snez.org? I have some questions and I can possibly help a bit more.